# Comparing two enum *types* for equivalence?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, enums

In my application, I have two equivalent `enum`s. One lives in the DAL, the other in the service contract layer. They have the same name (but are in different namespaces), and should have the same members and values.

I'd like to write a unit test that enforces this. So far, I've got the following:

```
public static class EnumAssert
{
    public static void AreEquivalent(Type x, Type y)
    {
        // Enum.GetNames and Enum.GetValues return arrays sorted by value.
        string[] xNames = Enum.GetNames(x);
        string[] yNames = Enum.GetNames(y);

        Assert.AreEqual(xNames.Length, yNames.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < xNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(xNames[i], yNames[i]);
        }

        // TODO: How to validate that the values match?
    }
}
```

This works fine for comparing the names, but how do I check that the values match as well?

(I'm using NUnit 2.4.6, but I figure this applies to any unit test framework)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
var xValues = Enum.GetValues(x);
var yValues = Enum.GetValues(y);

for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Length; i++)
{
    Assert.AreEqual((int)xValues.GetValue(i), (int)yValues.GetValue(i));
}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried Assert.AreEqual((int)xValues[i], (int)yValues[i]) and it was having none of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would flip the way you check around. It is easier to get a name from a value instead of a value from a name. Iterate over the values and check the names at the same time.

```
public static class EnumAssert
{
    public static void AreEquivalent(Type x, Type y)
    {
        // Enum.GetNames and Enum.GetValues return arrays sorted by value.
        var xValues = Enum.GetValues(x);
        var yValues = Enum.GetValues(y);

        Assert.AreEqual(xValues.Length, yValues.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Length; i++)
        {
            var xValue = xValues.GetValue( i );
            var yValue = yValues.GetValue( i );
            Assert.AreEqual(xValue, yValue);
            Assert.AreEqual( Enum.GetName( x, xValue ), Enum.GetName( y, yValue ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are testing for int equivalence and string equivalence of two different enums, you're missing a cast: Assert.AreEqual(xValue, yValue); should probably be Assert.AreEqual((int)xValue, (int)yValue);. In that case, this is a more thorough check than the chosen answer.

Comment: This answer is correct, but you also need to switch the x,y as a second pass so you check it both ways. Otherwise, you could have extra ones in the y type that are not in the x type.